# QSyntaxHighLighter и QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qsyntaxhighlighter

Есть определённый формат для каждого символа.

```
dict_of_formats = {'sin' : QTextCharFormat(), 'cos' : QTextCharFormat()}
```

Как правильно реализовать выделение этих строк в текстовом поле с помощью `QSyntaxHighLighter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно наследоваться от [QSyntaxHighlighter](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) и переопределить метод [highlightBlock](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html#highlightBlock).

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QSyntaxHighlighter, QTextCharFormat, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRegularExpression


class MyHighlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        char_format.setForeground(Qt.darkMagenta)

        expression = QRegularExpression(r"\b(cos|sin)\b")
        it = expression.globalMatch(text)
        while it.hasNext():
            match = it.next()
            self.setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), char_format)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = QTextEdit()
    mw.setText("x = sin(1)\nb = cos(sin(PI));")

    highlighter = MyHighlighter(mw.document())

    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если нужно поддержать несколько форматов, то нужно немного доработать наш `MyHighlighter`:

```
class MyHighlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.regexp_by_format = dict()

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        char_format.setForeground(Qt.darkMagenta)
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\bsin\b'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        char_format.setFontItalic(True)
        char_format.setForeground(Qt.darkCyan)
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\bcos\b'] = char_format

    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        for regexp, char_format in self.regexp_by_format.items():
            expression = QRegularExpression(regexp)
            it = expression.globalMatch(text)
            while it.hasNext():
                match = it.next()
                self.setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), char_format)
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]