# Как сделать подсветку для .ini файлов в pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, ini, highlighting

Я делаю небольшой текстовый редактор для мака на pyqt5 и хочу чтобы была возможность подсвечивать ini , json и другие файлы настроек (текстовые).
Я попробовал QScintilla ,но меня в ней не устроило то , что я создал несколько тем для редактора , а применить их к  QScintilla нельзя.

Как можно подсвечивать ini файлы в простом виджете QTextEdit?

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать, что вы пробовали и что у вас не получается?

Comment: Мои наработаки по подсветке http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/555843/17974 на с++ Два этапа, 1 - сделать ф-цию подсветить с-по (в примере есть). 2-просканировать текст и вызвать ф-цию подсветки фрагмента. Рекомендую не использовать regex, а делать обычное сравнение символа, ну максимум strstr (или какой у неё аналог в питоне)

Comment: Не питоне нет никакого strstr , это делается , либо через replace , либо  через regexp.И регулярки дают больше возможностей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dark theme:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyHighlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.regexp_by_format = dict()



        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(False)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("aqua"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\='] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(True)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("aqua"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'(.+?)(\=|\s|\b)'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Light)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("yellow"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'(\=|\s\=)(.*)'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("gray"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\[(.+?)\]'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("lightgray"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'(\;|\#)(.+?)$'] = char_format

    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        for regexp, char_format in self.regexp_by_format.items():
            expression = QRegularExpression(regexp)
            it = expression.globalMatch(text)
            while it.hasNext():
                match = it.next()
                self.setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), char_format)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = QTextEdit()
    mw.setText(open("settings.ini").read())
    mw.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit{font-size:20px;background-color: black; color: white;}")

    highlighter = MyHighlighter(mw.document())

    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Вот еще кстати для некоторых других файлов:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MyHighlighter(QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.regexp_by_format = dict()
        self.initForIni()
    def initForIni(self):
        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(False)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("red"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\='] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("red"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'(.+?)(\=|\s|\b)'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(True)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("white"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'(\=|\s\=)(.*)'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("gray"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\[(.+?)\]'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("lightgray"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'(\;|\#)(.+?)$'] = char_format

    def initForCss(self):

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(False)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("gray"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r':'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(False)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("gray"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'(.+?)(\{|\b\{)'] = char_format
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\}'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Light)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("red"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'(.*)\:'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(True)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("#87e7ff"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\:(.*)'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("gray"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\/\*(.*)\*\/'] = char_format

    def initForJSON(self):

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(False)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("#87e7ff"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'.'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(True)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("#ffb787"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'(true|false|null)'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(False)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("red"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\"(.+?)\"'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Light)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("gray"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\{'] = char_format
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\}'] = char_format
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\,'] = char_format
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\#'] = char_format #comments in python style

    def initForXML(self):

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(False)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("white"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'.'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(False)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("#87e7ff"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\<(.+?)\>'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(True)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("red"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'(\<|\>)'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("orange"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\"(.+?)\"'] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("red"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'='] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("green"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\b\s(.+?)='] = char_format

        char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        char_format.setFontItalic(True)
        char_format.setForeground(QColor("gray"))
        self.regexp_by_format[r'\<\!\-\-\>(.+?)\-\-\>'] = char_format





    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        for regexp, char_format in self.regexp_by_format.items():
            expression = QRegularExpression(regexp)
            it = expression.globalMatch(text)
            while it.hasNext():
                match = it.next()
                self.setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), char_format)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = QTextEdit()
    mw.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit{font-size:20px;background-color: #000000; color: white;}")

    highlighter = MyHighlighter(mw.document())

    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Код основан на этом:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/917849/qsyntaxhighlighter-%D0%B8-qtextedit